# Detect which side of uitableviewcell has been click: left or right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to distinguish which side of a row in a uitableview has been clicked?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  //which side of row has been detected left or right
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a bit more context to determine the use of this? Can you describe the situation we're talking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subclass UITableViewCell. In your subclass, you can make an iVar `wasTouchOnLeft`. Then override `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded` like the example below:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=(UITouch *)[touches anyObject];
    if([touch locationInView:self].x< (0.5 * self.frame.size.width) )
    {
        NSLog(@"Touched Left");
        wasTouchOnLeft=YES;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Touched Right");
        wasTouchOnLeft=NO;
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of your `UITableViewController` you can then access the `wasTouchOnLeft` variable for the cell.

Comment: Clean and Simple, yet very powerful!  Note:  For anyone using Landscape or developing on other devices with larger than 320 width, Consider using < self.frame.size.width / 2 instead of fixed "160" as the sizes may be dynamic depending on which device application is installed on or orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Newbyman. I am updating the code to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine this directly in this method.
But if you really want this feature create a custom tableview cell that has two big buttons (one left one on the right side) or apply a touch recognizer on the cell.

If you have this delegate the action to your controller
(You could also store it in the cell and access it via)

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(((YourCustomTableCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).clickedSideProperty) action;
else anotherAction;
}
```

But better delegate it from the table cell than access it from didSelectRow…

Comment: Thanks, Tried it your way with two buttons but scrolling up and down the tableview is very slow. im basically turning the tableview into a image grid, so you can select and image to see more info.

Comment: Do you use an reusableIdentifier for the custom cell?